# Enable authorization on sitemap provider

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to enable Authorization on the Site map provider. We have enabled anonymous access to the site and we want the Site map provider to be visible only to authorized users.

I tried securityTrimmingEnabled="true" in the web.config. No change!

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, security trimming comes out-of-the box. So, if you break the inheritance for a particular site and grant access to sets of users with SharePoint Groups, for example, then the navigation will be automatically security-trimmed.

If you're looking for something specific, can you explain in more detail? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the roles attribute on each siteMapNode ?

Comment: I am using the default Site map providers provided by SharePoint. Can you please tell me how to do that?